Github action skips workflow if branch created from action
I have a GitHub action designed for all three events with branch filter:
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "release/**"
  push:
    branches:
      - "release/**"
  create:
    branches:
      - "release/**"

This action triggered successfully with on:create if I create a branch using:

web interface
with my local git repo using

git checkout -b release/bla-bla
git push origin release/bla-bla

but when I'm doing the same from github action:
- name: Create new branch
  run: |
    git checkout -b release/bla-bla
    git push https://${{ env.github-user }}:${{ env.github-token }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }}.git release/bla-bla

it won't. How can I fix this?

you need to checkout the code first before creating a branch.
add a step to check out the code and it should work
